# SFP+ Connector Won't Latch

Tags: sfp, meraki, mellanox

We're trying to connect a Cisco Meraki MS225-48 switch to a Mellanox SN2100 switch using [this breakout cable](https://www.mellanoxstore.com/products/mellanox-mc2609130-003-passive-copper-hybrid-cable-eth-40gbe-to-4x10gbe-qsfp-to-4xsfp-3m.html). However, the SFP+ end of the cable does not physically latch into the Meraki SFP+ ports (i.e. they don't "click" into place), and even with the cables pushed in as far as they will go, the Meraki switch will not recognize that anything is plugged in. It *feels* like the PCB on the connector is seating, but I'm not certain.

Any advice?

Comment: Troubleshoot better...

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a single cable? This could be a hardware defect from the manufacturer so this could be as simple as having them switch out the cable for you.

Do you have another DAC cable of any kind to try out in that port? Doesn't need to be compatible, just the form factor should be the same. This will allow you to test to see if this other cable is able to click into place.

If possible try this cable you bought in a different switch with SFP/SFP+ ports and see if they click. Again compatibility does not matter as all you are testing is if the hardware fits correctly.